# modification in text file by batch script

Tags: powershell, batch-file, double-quotes

I have a text file like

```
KML|ID|CODE|----------and so on  //Header

abc|123|hasc|ikjh|0.9888|udee|*|0.00|gsgs|-367.99||||||9.18282823334| //Body

end of file
```

I want to put " "(double quotes) in each column from start to end by batch script or powershell script

I want my output

```
"abc"|"123"|"hasc"|"ikjh"|"0.9888"|"udee"|"*"|"0.00"|"gsgs"|"-367.99"||||||"9.18282823334"|
```

Comment: PowerShell has cmdlets specifically for working with CSV files, e.g. `ConvertTo-Csv`, `ConvertFrom-Csv`, `Import-Csv`, and `Export-Csv`. Please read the help information for those and try to code something. This is not a free code writing service. Please also note that there are some differences between PowerShell versions, so make sure that any reference material you use is valid for the intended version you are using.

Comment: Looks like `Import-Csv -Path 'X:\PathTo\thefile.csv' -Delimiter '|' | Export-Csv -Path 'X:\PathTo\UpdatedFile.csv' -Delimiter '|' -NoTypeInformation`

Answer (score 0):

This answer is based from Theo's comment :

---

```bat
@echo off
Title Export 2 CSV File
Set "InputFile=%1"
If [%InputFile%] EQU [] echo/ You should Drag and Drop an Inputfile over this batch script "%~nx0" & TimeOut /T 8 /NoBreak>nul & exit /b 1
Powershell -C "Import-Csv -Path '%InputFile%' -Delimiter '|' | Export-Csv -Path '.\UpdatedFile.csv' -Delimiter '|' -NoTypeInformation"
If Exist ".\UpdatedFile.csv" Start "" /MAX Notepad ".\UpdatedFile.csv"
```